# Simple json return value asp.net with webservices

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-2.0

Simple json return value asp.net with webservices i will dispaly the code that i tried

When Button clicks it returns some value in json

### Asp.net HTML Coding

```
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"  />
```

### JQuery Coding

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        txtNameValue = $("#txtName").val();
       alert("button clicked");

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL+"/HelloWorld",
        data: "{'name':'" + txtNameValue + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success:function(response) {
        alert(response);
            console.log(typeof response);

        }
        });

    });    
});
```

### Web Services File class file

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class FirstPageWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public FirstPageWebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
   [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld() {

        string s = "Hello World";
       return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(s);

    }

}
```

[image: String Image]

[image: String return]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: check the image above new to this so getting confused when it returns the value as string (typeof response)

Comment: @SwathiVenugopal Are you not getting it right ?

Comment: ya i need it in json format

Comment: Isn't "Hello world" a string, therefore a valid Json output ? You could try serializing a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: can you please tell how to change the code

Comment: @SwathiVenugopal you don't need to change code you are returning a string therefore there is no difference. If you return an object of some class or a list or some other thing you will get your desired result.

Comment: Sending data like this  data: "{'name':'" + txtNameValue + "'}",  but getting the same string again   check my jquery coding

Comment: Ok to make things clear make a class with some properties in your service and return an object of that class than you will see actual difference.

Comment: sorry can't get you clearly check the image above zoom it for clear image